# Javascript type error - not a function return if variable previously defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that measures the width of an element:

```
function distanceToCaret(textElement,caretIndex){

    line = findLineViaCaret(textElement,caretIndex);
    relativeIndex = caretIndex - line.startIndex;
    textToCaret = line.text.substring(0, relativeIndex);

    hiddenElement = textElement.clone(); //copies font settings and width
    hiddenElement.empty();//clear text
    hiddenElement.css("visibility", "hidden");
    hiddenElement.css("width", "auto"); //so width can be measured
    hiddenElement.css("display", "inline-block"); //so width can be measured

    jQuery('body').append(hiddenElement); // height doesn't exist until inserted into document

    hiddenElement.text(textToCaret); //add character to get height
    width = hiddenElement.width();
    hiddenElement.remove();
    return width;
}
```

I call it with:

```
distanceToCaret = distanceToCaret($(this), thisIndex);
```

The first time I call this function it would return say, "72", the second time call it I get the error:

```
TypeError: '72' is not a function (evaluating 'distanceToCaret($(this), thisIndex)')
```

In fact if `disctanceToCaret` is defined at all before I call `distanceToCaret = distanceToCaret();` I get this error. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is

```
distanceToCaret = distanceToCaret($(this), thisIndex);
```

Rename the function `distanceToCaret` to `getDstanceToCaret`, then

```
distanceToCaret = getDstanceToCaret($(this), thisIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because functions are first-class objects in javascript. So this: `function distanceToCaret(textElement,caretIndex){ ... }` is the same as this: `distanceToCaret = function(textElement,caretIndex){ ... }`. That is to say, you can assign a function to a variable, and when you define a function the normal way, that's just a shortcut to assign it to the specified variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function named `distanceToCaret`, and assigning the result to `distanceToCaret`. In JavaScript, functions are not special. There variable `distanceToCaret` holds a reference to the funciton, so changing/setting the value of `distanceToCaret` means you have lost the reference to your function.

If you use a different name for the returned value, this problem should go away:

```
var distance = distanceToCaret($(this), thisIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning return width(72) to variable distanceToCaret so when you call distanceToCaret function it is calling variable instead of your function so change your variable name distanceToCaret to _distanceToCaret and try it

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your function definition with the result from executing your function after the first execution.

```
function distanceToCaret(textElement,caretIndex){}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var distanceToCaret = function (textElement, caretIndex) {}
```

So you perform:

```
var distanceToCaret = function (textElement, caretIndex) {};
distanceToCaret = distanceToCaret(); // Now distanceToCaret is no longer a function
```